# SqlQuery throws exception in Ignite 2.0.0

Tags: ignite

I have just upgraded to V2.0.0 and tried the following code ..

```
SqlQuery diffSql = new SqlQuery(PendingAvGroup.class,
     " from PendingAvGroup as pnd  " +
     "where not exists(select 1 from " +
     "\"Processed_PendingAvGroup_cache\".PendingAvGroup prc " +
     " WHERE prc.resourceGroupId = pnd.resourceGroupId)"
     );
```

But i get the following error ..

Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "Pending_PendingAvGroup_cache.PENDINGAVGROUP._KEY" not found; 
SQL statement:
SELECT "Pending_PendingAvGroup_cache".PendingAvGroup._key, "Pending_PendingAvGroup_cache".PendingAvGroup._val from PendingAvGroup as pnd  where not exists(select 1 from "Processed_PendingAvGroup_cache".PendingAvGroup prc  WHERE prc.resourceGroupId = pnd.resourceGroupId) [42122-195]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345) ~[h2-1.4.195.jar:1.4.195]

Its appears that when ever I provide a FROM clause I get '._KEY" not found;' error ... even for a single table.

Id really appreciate anyones help on this ..
Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a quirky thing of SQL (I'm not sure if it is a standard or just H2). By default Ignite generates query with the original table name in select clause `"Pending_PendingAvGroup_cache".PendingAvGroup`, but it must actually use your alias `pnd` there.

To solve this you have to set the alias on `SqlQuery` and Ignite will generate correct query:

`SqlQuery diffSql = new SqlQuery(PendingAvGroup.class, "...").setAlias("pnd");`

Another option is to use `SqlFieldsQuery`:

`new SqlFieldsQuery("select _key, _val from ....")`